# How to deploy and run multiple different Azure Cloud Services on same Azure VM?

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

I have few services which has very low usage, but they are quite hardware intensive when they are used. Right now they run separately. Every of them has its own Web Role and Worker Roles. Every of this roles run on its own VM with specified size and instances count. That is I believe standard way.

I would like to rent one quite powerful VM from Azure, on which I would like to deploy every of my services. Ideally without changing structure of code so I can keep them in separate projects/solutions. They will run simultaneously and all of them will be accessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot deploy more than one cloud service package to a set of role instance vm's. If you want all of your services to run in a single role instance (or set of instances), you need to bundle all of your services into that role. How you do that, and how you organize your code, is strictly up to you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So do you thing, that to achieve my needs is it good solution to rent directly VM. Initiate Web Deploy on IIS on it and deploy my Azure Cloud Services Projects to this VM. If i am right i can keep my code for services separate as it is now and run them all on one virtual machine. What do you think?